# Question about vocal technique

Tags: technique

I wonder if someone could help me with identifying vocal technique of the lead singer in Mgla. Here's the video

. Is it based on 
 usage of false chords or not?

Answer (score 1):

It's called "[Death Growl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_growl)" and it is an [extended vocal technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_vocal_technique). Also known as, "death metal vocals, guttural vocals, death grunts, growled vocals, unclean vocals, harsh vocals, and brutal growl." Because everyone's voice is different, no two death growls are likely to sound exactly alike...

There are plenty of tutorials on youtube about how to achieve this:

Be careful when practicing the technique and don't overdo it or you could seriously damage your vocal cords.